# AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration how to use MessageAttributes in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I have tried several variations of using `MessageAttributes` in my CloudFormation document but I can't get it to work. This is what I've got:

```yaml
HttpApiSqsIntegration:
  Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
  Properties:
    ApiId: !Ref HttpApiRef
    CredentialsArn: !GetAtt MyHttpApiRole.Arn
    IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
    IntegrationSubtype: SQS-SendMessage
    PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
    RequestParameters:
      QueueUrl: !Ref InputMessageSqs
      MessageBody: $request.body
      MessageAttributes.entry.1.Name: foo
      MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.StringValue: bar
      MessageAttributes.entry.1.Value.DataType: String
```

I'm following the format specified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_MessageAttributeValue.html), and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services-reference.html) but it gives the following error message:

```
Parameter: MessageAttributes.entry.1.Name does not fit schema for Operation: 
SQS-SendMessage. (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: ...; Proxy: null)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this in CloudFormation but managed to get it working from the web console. I imagine the syntax is equivalent to the one you would use in CloudFormation.

For example, suppose you want to add an attribute called `timestamp` with value equal to the request header `x-timestamp`. You would use this syntax in the `MessageAttributes` field:

```
{ "timestamp": { "DataType": "String", "StringValue": "${request.header.x-timestamp}" } }
```

This is (very badly) documented in the SQS API reference.
See the [SendMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html) and [MessageAttributeValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_MessageAttributeValue.html) pages.

The correct part of the documentation is where it says that MessageAttributes has to be a "`String` to `MessageAttributeValue` object map".
The rest of the documentation where it mentions `MessageAttribute.N.Name` seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are following the wrong specification. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration.html#cfn-apigatewayv2-integration-requestparameters) is the right one.

> RequestParameters For WebSocket APIs, a key-value map specifying
> request parameters that are passed from the method request to the
> backend. The key is an integration request parameter name and the
> associated value is a method request parameter value or static value
> that must be enclosed within single quotes and pre-encoded as required
> by the backend. The method request parameter value must match the
> pattern of method.request.{location}.{name} , where {location} is
> querystring, path, or header; and {name} must be a valid and unique
> method request parameter name.
>
> For HTTP API integrations with a specified integrationSubtype, request
> parameters are a key-value map specifying parameters that are passed
> to AWS_PROXY integrations. You can provide static values, or map
> request data, stage variables, or context variables that are evaluated
> at runtime. To learn more, see Working with AWS service integrations
> for HTTP APIs.
>
> For HTTP API integrations without a specified integrationSubtype
> request parameters are a key-value map specifying how to transform
> HTTP requests before sending them to the backend. The key should
> follow the pattern :<header|querystring|path>. where
> action can be append, overwrite or remove. For values, you can provide
> static values, or map request data, stage variables, or context
> variables that are evaluated at runtime. To learn more, see
> Transforming API requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do within a CloudFormation template:

```yaml
HttpApiSqsIntegration:
  Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
  Properties:
    ApiId: !Ref HttpApiRef
    CredentialsArn: !GetAtt MyHttpApiRole.Arn
    IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
    IntegrationSubtype: SQS-SendMessage
    PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
    RequestParameters:
      QueueUrl: !Ref InputMessageSqs
      MessageBody: $request.body
      MessageAttributes: >-
        {
          "foo": {
            "DataType": "String",
            "StringValue": "bar"
          }
        }
```

If you need a dynamic value you can do:

```yaml
    RequestParameters:
      QueueUrl: !Ref InputMessageSqs
      MessageBody: $request.body
      MessageAttributes: >-
        {
          "foo": {
            "DataType": "String",
            "StringValue": "${context.path}"
          }
        }
```

Note that `MessageAttributes` must be a valid JSON string.

See: https://awsteele.com/blog/2021/09/06/api-gateway-http-apis-and-sqs-messageattributes.html